# HTML Scrollable using scrollbar but not using mousewheel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a weird issue on my site alfredcodes.com

If you click latest creations, or click the menu to view projects, this content is scrollable content but it does not allow scrolling using the mousewheel..

If I try to inspect element highlight the section with class showcase and switch off and on any of the z-index or overflow options AND OR adjust the windows height alittle bit the mouse scroll starts working again..

Really bizarre and I can't seem to figure out why.. Please help

Is it because the transition effect needs to reset the DOM height but isn't?

Comment: It's scrollable with the mousewheel for me (Chrome 40 and Firefox 37 Mac).

Comment: the problem is where the mouse click focus is. If the user hasn't clicked or hasn't given focus to the scrolling area the mouse scroll won't be applicable. You could try using javscript to give focus to the scrolling content when the window loads.

Comment: I'm currently testing on a windows chrome at the moment, the weirdest thing happens, when I have inspect element and have the developer tool as a seperate window then try refreshing it scrolls for about 2 seconds and then stops..

Comment: What kind of script would I need to give focus onscrolling content? Why is it that when I chagne the window height the scroll works? Is there a way to see what the current scroll obejct is?